# How to import a CSV with an hour/minute string as a timestamp to panda dataset

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataset, timeofday

I need to import a CSV to a panda dataset.
The CSV has columns with just a time of the day, an example is a columns with "16:45" at a minutes level, another column has "21:03:39" at the seconds level.
Importing it using read_cvs and using parse_dates for the columns will not keep it as is, it will convert it to "2022/10/07 16:45" or "2022/10/07 21:03:39" for the second example.
How can I import it and have the type as Time without adding the date?

Comment: please post a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  I tried with just two rows with time as you indicated and it got imported without date

Comment: I don't understand what data you have. Better show table or even better create code with we could copy and test.

Comment: Below is imported from CSV:
|       DATE       |   HOUR |
------------------------
| 2022/03/29  |  14:00   |    
| 2021/06/25  |   21:45   |
------------------------

DATE is imported as datetime.
If HOUR is imported as datetime it is converted to datetime with today's date "2022:10:10 14:00"

    import datetime as dt
    import pandas as pd
    parse_dates=['DATE']
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath, parse_dates=parse_dates, 
    infer_datetime_format=True)

Maybe datetime is not the correct type, but I could not find a different time to host the time only.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```py
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, '16:45'],
                   [2, '21:03:39']], columns=['x1', 'time_string'])
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_string']).apply(lambda t: dt.time(t.hour, t.minute, t.second))

# Output these to show it works
df.head()
df['time'].apply(lambda x: type(x))
```

Returns this:

```
   x1 time_string      time
0   1       16:45  16:45:00
1   2    21:03:39  21:03:39

0    <class 'datetime.time'>
1    <class 'datetime.time'>
Name: time, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you, its close, the only thing is that the time column type, is an object, and not a datetime:
`
    >>> df.dtypes
    x1                    int64
    time_string    object
    time                object
    dtype: object
`

Comment: I updated the code to show that the data type is actually a `datetime.time`.  Pandas obscures the data types sometimes, but if you look at the individual values (using `apply` here), you can see they're the right data type.